# Generating Excel to JSON Data

Tags: json, react-native, api, parsing

I have a website that contains some data and downloads an excel about those data. I have the need to build a React Native mobile app and consume the data of the excel. I thought it was quicker to find a system that would convert the excel data to a JSON API and share the data in real time so that I can consume the API on my mobile app. This system should also manage to download the excel file by downloading and parsing it continuously so that the data are up to date. Does there exist any system online that makes this possible? If not does it exist any React Native library that downloads the file from web (not having it in the file system) and parses it?
Thank you